# How to make a Windows local group default for new users?

Tags: windows-10, openvpn

I have created a local group on Windows Pro ("OpenVPN Administrators"). I want every new user that gets created on the machine to have this local group. How can I achieve this?

I have explored the possibility of writing a script to add existing users to this local group. I want to automate this process for new users elegantly. I don't want to keep running this script again and again to account for new users.

Is there a way to configure local groups that should be assigned to a new user?

Comment: Just add a group e.g. the existing local users group to that group?

Comment: Hi @Seth! Can you give an example on how to do that?

Comment: @Seth nesting of local groups is not allowed on Windows
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/ee681621(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Interesting, you can set it up using PowerShell but indeed it won't be reflected in `[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()` it seems. You could try to change your configuration to just use the standard users group instead of your special group.